# How do i filter out certain text with awk but also print the text?

Tags: awk

I need to sort out some data, but I cant figure out how to exclude text from a field, but also print the rest of that line without the specified text. I have only been able to figure out how to delete the entire line, which is what I don't want. Here is a command that shows the output with the data i need, but when i try to use the other command to exclude data it ends up deleting the entire field:

Here is an example of the source text that im trying to filter. I cant paste the entire log or output here because its really long, but i can provide pieces of it here: If it will help someone, here is a full log, note that not all the data is like the rest, a few lines are different, but i am willing to manually filter out a few lines that don't match the rest: https://pastebin.com/ifVK2BHg

```
[16:07:29] [Server thread/INFO]: OkqySeany lost connection: Disconnected
[16:24:42] [Server thread/INFO]: DraconicPiggy lost connection: Disconnected
[19:35:49] [User Authenticator #8/INFO]: UUID of player Anviloh_YT is 009fd2cd-c5da-4639-b3b9-ef90b7438c99
[19:39:43] [User Authenticator #9/INFO]: UUID of player DraconicPiggy is b075ce61-dcef-4d40-a674-100a07b361c4
[20:16:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Anviloh_YT lost connection: Disconnected
[20:19:57] [Server thread/INFO]: DraconicPiggy lost connection: Disconnected
```

The command that prints out field $4, but also has #INFO on it:

```
    awk '{print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $8 }' *.filtered.log
```

```
[16:07:29] OkqySeany  
[16:24:42] DraconicPiggy  
[19:35:49] #8/INFO]: Anviloh_YT  
[19:39:43] #9/INFO]: DraconicPiggy  
[20:16:00] Anviloh_YT  
[20:19:57] DraconicPiggy
```

Field 4 has some data that i need, but the #INFO is something I want gone so I tried this:

```
    awk '$4 !~ /#/ {print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $8 }' *.filtered.log
```

But that command just deletes the field i need:

```
[16:07:29]      OkqySeany  
[16:24:42]      DraconicPiggy  
[20:16:00]      Anviloh_YT  
[20:19:57]      DraconicPiggy
```

As you can see the 2 in the middle are gone, how do i delete #INFO without deleting the whole line? I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
[16:07:29] OkqySeany  
[16:24:42] DraconicPiggy  
[19:35:49] Anviloh_YT  
[19:39:43] DraconicPiggy  
[20:16:00] Anviloh_YT  
[20:19:57] DraconicPiggy
```

Comment: Could you please post more clear sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then. As it's not much clear as of now.

Comment: The sample i gave you is about as clear as it can get. Its not very complicated data. It just goes like that for about 400 lines with various user data, its data from a log file that has been sorted and formatted with another script, then dumped into another log file. If i gave you a more clear sample of the input, it would just be more lines of data pretty much the exact same as the one already there. The expected output is just field $1, which is the timestamps, field $4 but preferably without #INFO, and then field $8. Ill update my question to put down the output i am trying to get.

Comment: Your posted output seems to be completely disconnected from your posted input. [edit] your question to fix that to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and the output you get/expect **from that input**, not the output you get/expect from some other input. Keep it simple for us. See [ask]. Also tell us if there are any tabs in your input (as opposed to blank chars) and, if so, where they occur.

Comment: Okay i updated it to make the source sample match the other samples.

Comment: What is the 8th field value?

Comment: Because of the different text lengths, field 8 is the username field for the one with the "UUID" in it. But prints nothing for the other lines, which is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample data, looks like the output should include 1 line of output per 1 line of input (timestmap and userid), and that there are two "types" of lines ("Server" and "User"), where the user id is in different position on each line.

Consider the following `awk` script

```
awk '
$2 == "[Server" { print $1, $4 ; next }
$2 == "[User" { print $1, $8 ; next }
' *.filtered.log
```

Comment: With some tweaks to your script, I ended up being able to print out a few more fields that I needed. Since there was no relevant logical data on the "User" line, i resorted to using notepad++ to replace all instances of UUID with Connected. The "Server" line already had disconnected so i didnt have to do anything for that: https://pastebin.com/18pYeTAM

Comment: @Darkdestroyer12 I'm not sure if you your meant to post any additionlal quetions. Sound that you have a solution working, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by fields but by the example data you post, you want to skip the second square bracketed group (logically field 2) and print the first word from logical field 3 (seems like a log line).  However couldn't figure out the significance of field 8.

Two interpretations might be

After deleting the second logical field print the first word and the one 4 away

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/ \[[^]]+\]/,""); print $1,$2,$6}' file

[05:03:08]:     UUID    is
[05:06:08]:     deathweek
```

Or, print the first and last word from the log line

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/ \[[^]]+\]/,""); print $1,$2,$NF}' file

[05:03:08]:     UUID    50c4aed1-900f-4397-b8ac-73b232df90fc
[05:06:08]:     deathweek       Disconnected
```

As in almost all questions, especially here matching input and output samples would have helped to figure out what is really asked for.  Otherwise we can only have an educated guess...

Comment: Ah, my bad, i probably should have given some examples of the source. I will update my question for that.

Comment: The command you gave me doesn't give the output that i want, but thats my fault for not giving a valid source first. it gives me this: https://pastebin.com/A3ETSDvC

Comment: I dont understand why everyone is getting confused? The input and output are from the same source? EDIT: Never mind, i think i found out why everyone is confused. The source input now matches.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the substr() & match() functions

You need to turn `#4/INFO]:` into `#4`, i.e. delete the last 7 characters. The "Sever thread rows are for disconnections and don't contain the `#` field.

Disconnections are slightly tricky to handle as there are two versions of the disconnect:

1. `…iHezi lost connection: Disconnected`
2. `…com.mojang…authlib.GameProfile@6c2ffd3b[id=<null>,name=GLX27,properties=…`

### The script

Create a file called `test.awk` containing:

```
$2 != "[Server" {
  slashPos = index($4, "/" )
  if ( slashPos > 0 ) {
    cleanField4 = substr( $4, 1, slashPos - 1 )
  } else {
    cleanField4 = $4
  }
  print "B" NR,$1 "\t\t" cleanField4 "\t" $8
  next
}

"lost connection" {
  if ( index( $0, "id=<null>" ) > 0 ) {
    match( $4, /name=\y(.+)\y,properties/, array )
    $4 = array[1]
    $7 = $NF
  }
  print $1 "\t" $7 "\t" $4
}
```

### Command line

To use this from the command line, change your command to:

```
awk -f test.awk *.filtered.log
```

### Output from from script, using latest sample data

This is just the first few lines of the generated report:

```
[04:25:32]              #1      DraconicPiggy
[04:27:46]      Disconnected    DraconicPiggy
[04:27:52]              #2      DraconicPiggy
[05:01:01]              #3      Myshiro
[05:03:08]              #4      deathweek
[05:06:08]      Disconnected    deathweek
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this piece of code. I am still learning about awk. I tried using it in the terminal to no avail.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example terminal command .

Comment: Thank you, however this ends up subtracting from all $4 fields. Not sure if i'm doing something wrong. https://pastebin.com/T5tC9BD0

Comment: I appreciate your help, and there's a good chance i did something wrong, but the code you gave me subtracts from all $4 fields when i use it. Oh and thanks for your help with the previous scripting, i would have never gotten this far!

Comment: The porblem is due to the Server messages which should be ignored. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Answer updated with improved script that works with your latest PasteBin data.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. That's a nice script, but it only shows the logins, not the logouts.